# String-array puts a comma after item text

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a textview from a string-array. That works fine, but this puts a comma at the end of the item string.

Here is my code:

**.java**

```
View faqs = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_faq, container, false);
TextView respuesta1 = (TextView) faqs.findViewById(R.id.respuesta1);
Resources res = getResources();
String[] pregunta1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.pregunta1);
respuesta1.setText(Arrays.toString(pregunta1).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

**.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/respuesta1" />
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="pregunta1">
    <item>Suspender cualquier método de arranque de vello por un mes (cera, Epilady, pincita).\n\n</item>
    <item>Durante ese mes podés utilizar métodos de corte (crema depilatoria, maquinita de afeitar).\n\n</item>
    <item>El día anterior al turno debés rasurar perfectamente la zona a tratar.\n\n</item>
    <item>De haber estado en tratamiento con ROACUTAN (para el acné) dejar pasar 6 meses antes de solicitar turno.\n\n</item>
    <item>Asistir con la piel limpia, sin crema ni desodorante en la zona a tratar.\n</item>
    <item>No exponerse al sol 48hs antes.\n\n</item>
    <item>Se puede realizar en verano sobre piel bronceada pero no irritada.\n\n</item>
</string-array>
```

**Result:**

[image: output example]

Comment: Hi, what is the value of Arrays.toString(pregunta1) ? ESP: que valor retorna Arrays.toString(pregunta1) ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Arrays.toString()`, use `TextUtils.join()`. Try this,

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] pregunta1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.pregunta1);
respuesta1.setText(TextUtils.join("", pregunta1));
```